# jenkins boolean parameter convert value to number

Tags: jenkins

I have a boolean parameter which I like to send its value in the excute windows batch command.
My excute windows batch command expects this parameter as number: true --> 1 and false --> 0.
How can I translate boolean parameter value to a number (as string)?

Comment: How does your job look like? A freestyle job, pipeline job using a `Jenkinsfile`?

Comment: It is a freestyle job

Comment: So it's just about windows batch files and converting from true to 1?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Parametized Build plugin --> boolean parameter. The value I get from this parameter is true/false. I have an application that one of its parameters uses this parameter and expects 0/1 value (not true/false).

Comment: any success on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin and some conditional steps in the build section.

It is easier to show this with a screen shot.

[image]

Note that it is a different variable name. So make sure to use the new variable name in the later build step that you need.